# Fragments or ViewPager not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with tabs. In the onCreate method of the activity I have the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_team);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        myTeam = i.getParcelableExtra("TeamObject");
        //MatchAsyncTask mat = new MatchAsyncTask()execute();

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTeam);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpTeam);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabsTeam);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar_team);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(myTeam.getName());

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.team_detail_header);
        String strImg1 = "f"+String.valueOf(myTeam.getId());
        int resId1 = getResources().getIdentifier(strImg1, "drawable", getPackageName());
        img.setImageResource(resId1);

    }
```

The code of the setWithViewPager functions is this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("TeamId",myTeam.getId());
        PlayerFragment pf = new PlayerFragment();
        pf.setArguments(args);

        InfoMatchFragment partidos = new InfoMatchFragment();

        adapter.addFrag(pf, "Plantel");
        adapter.addFrag(partidos, "Partidos");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And the adapter class for the ViewPager is:

```
static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

The problem happen when I iniciate the activity and the first fragment is load on first tab but when I swipe to second tabs, the same fragment is been showing.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Change you Adapter method and try this ways

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
         PlayerFragment pf = new PlayerFragment();
          //pf.setArguments(args);
                return pf;
            case 1: 
                return new InfoMatchFragment();

            default:
                return null;
        }
        }
```